# Calculate the expectation of the maximum of averaged random walks

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-walks, large-deviations

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be iid random variables with bounded second moment. The question is to calculate the exact value of $$\mathbb{E} \max_{1 \le j < \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_j}{j}.$$

Is there any principled approach to calculate or approximate this expectation in the literature? If not, can we still do something for some special distiributions of $X_1$?

Comment: You are looking for maximal inequalities (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality)

Comment: @AnthonyQuas doesn't the averaging throw one quite a bit off the martingale setting?

Comment: @IgorRivin: Hmmm now you mention it, yes, but there are ergodic maximal inequalities that do say this sort of thing. See for example equation (9) in Tao's lecture notes on ergodic theory.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/254a-lecture-9-ergodicity/

Comment: See the last answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147270/expected-supremum-of-average for an approach

Comment: $\frac {S_n} n $ is a backward martingale, so you can use that directly.  Also, I think the analogous problem for Brownian motion $sup_{t > 1} \frac {W_t} t$ has exact solution because the time change $s  = \frac 1 t$ changes it to sup of Brownian motion over (0,1).