# The min of the mean of iid exponential variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-walks, martingales

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots$ be iid exponential random variables with mean 1. It is well-known that $\min_{1\le j < \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_j}{j}$ follows the uniform distribution U(0,1). Can anyone help me find a reference to this result? Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not so sure that it's well known (do you a have source where it is explicitly stated?). If you're content with a MO-reference you can cite the last solution here:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147270/expected-supremum-of-average

Comment: So far, four of us have answered, and none of us likes any other answer enough for upvoting!

Comment: @Matt F.: I like both new proofs (Iosif's and yours). But I think the OP is asking for a reference in  the usual sense, i.e. earlier (earliest ) explicit appearance of the result.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\w{\mathfrak w}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$We have to show that $P(U<u)=u$ for $u\in(0,1)$, where
$$U:=\min_{j\ge1} \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_j}j$$
and $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid exponential random variables with mean $1$. This minimum is attained almost surely (a.s.), because, by the strong law of large numbers, $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_j}j\to1$ a.s. as $j\to\infty$, whereas $\inf_{j\ge1} \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_j}j<1$ a.s.

For each natural $j$ and each $u\in(0,1)$,
$$\begin{aligned}
U<u&\iff\exists j\ge1\ \;\sum_{i=1}^j X_i<ju \\ 
&\iff\exists j\ge1\ \;Y_{u,j}:=\sum_{i=1}^j(u-X_i)>0 \\ 
&\iff\bar Y_u>0, 
\end{aligned}\tag{1}$$
where $\bar Y_u:=\max_{j\ge0}Y_{u,j}$, with $Y_{u,0}=0$ (of course).
By the formula $E e^{i\la\bar Y}=\w_+(\la)/\w_+(0)$ at the very end of Section 19 of Chapter 4 (p. 105) and Theorem 2 in this chapter (pp. 106--107) of [Borovkov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-9866-3),
$$g_u(\la):=E e^{i\la\bar Y_u}=\frac{(1-u)i\la}{1+i\la-e^{i\la u}}$$
for all real $\la$.
Note also that $\bar Y_u\ge Y_{u,0}=0$.
So, by Proposition 1 in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715215002722?via%3Dihub)  or its [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5928) ,
$$P(\bar Y_u>0)=E\,\text{sign}\,\bar Y_u
=\frac1{\pi i}\,\int_\R \frac{g_u(\la)}\la\,d\la
=\frac1{\pi i}\,\int_\R h_u(\la)\,d\la \tag{2}
,$$
where
$$h_u(\la):=\frac{g_u(\la)-g_u(\infty-)}\la
=(1-u)\frac{1-e^{i \la u}}{\la(e^{i \la u}-1-i\la)}$$
and the integrals are understood in the principal value sense.

$\require{\ulem}$

In view of (1), it remains to show that the integrals in (2) equal $\pi i u$ for all $u\in(0,1)$.

This is now proved at [An integral identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377011/an-integral-identity)

Answer (score 0):

We can explicitly keep track of both the running average and the running minimum average.

Let $f(k,m,r)$ be the probability density that after $k$ variables, the minimum average so far is $m$, and the current running average is $r$ with $m<r$.

Let $g(k,m)$ be the probability density that after $k$ variables, the minimum average so far is $m$, and this is also the running average so far.

I claim that for $k\ge2:$
\begin{align}
f(k,m,r) &= \frac{e^{-kr}(kr)^{k-1}}{r(k-2)!}1_{[m<r]}\\
g(k,m) &= \frac{e^{-km}(km)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\end{align}

Once we have these formulas, we can guess the limiting distribution from the fact that we are only interested in $f$ and not $g$ (since after many draws, the minimum average has almost surely happened in the past), and only in $r=1$ (since after many draws, the running average is almost surely 1). So we can guess that the limiting distribution is a normalization of $f(k,m,1)$, which we can read off as $1_{[m<1]}$, and is the uniform distribution that was desired.

More formally it is enough to show that
$$\int_0^\infty f(k,m,r)dr + g(k,m) \to 1_{[m<r]} \text{ as }k \to \infty$$
which I have verified numerically. The first term is just $\Gamma[k-1,km]/(k-2)!$, so the proof of the limit is probably easy even though I haven't found it yet.

Returning to the claim, the formulas for $f$ and $g$ can be proved by an induction for $k'=k+1$:
\begin{align}
f(k',m,r)=
&\int_{x=m}^{k'r/k} f(k,m,x)k'e^{-k'r+kx}dx \\
&+ g(k,m)k'e^{-k'r+km}\\
g(k',m)=
&\int_{r=m}^{\infty}\int_{x=m}^{r} f(k,x,r)k'e^{-k'm+kr}dx\,dr \\
&+ \int_{x=m}^{\infty}g(k,x)k'e^{-k'm+kx}dx
\end{align}
The four terms on the right-hand sides of those equations are just what is needed to keep track of the four possibilities for $m<r$ or $m=r$ and $m_{old}<r_{old}$ or $m_{old}=r_{old}$.

Comment: Since exponential distribution is continuous, $f(k,m,r) = g(k, m)  =0$ for any $m$. Maybe you mean the density function? 

Still, if we take $r = 1$ and $m <1$ in the expression for $f(k,m,r)$ in your claim, then  $f(k,m,r)  \sim \sqrt{\frac{n}{2 \pi}}$ grows to infinity, thus it cannot be a density.

Comment: @Sinusx, yes, a probability density. But what is $n$ in your comment? Whatever it is, I suspect that the asymptotic analysis in the comment is neglecting the factor of $1_{[m<r]}$ in the formula for $f(k,m,r)$.

Comment: I meant $k$ instead of $n$. If $f$ is  a joint density in $(m,r)$, then it is not necessarily a problem if it grows to infinity for $r = 1$ so the second part of my first comment does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant and more general result can be derived from Renyi representation of exponential order statistics. See my book Statistics: *New foundations, toolkit, machine learning recipes*, pp 133-138.

Comment: I am looking at a copy of the book but I do not see how this works. If the Renyi representation gives the distributions of distances between the order statistics, how does that help for the minimum of the running averages?

Comment: Here we go: http://frenchlane.com/Booklet_stats_v8.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I still don't see how the Renyi representation on p. 135 answers the question, and pp. 136-138 seem irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure is this helps: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-variance-of-the-range-for-exponential-distributions. While it deals with the range, results about the $\min$ can be derived from it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

(Since you are looking for a reference, I turn my comment above into an answer:)

A proof using classical fluctuation theory is given my answer to

[Expected supremum of average?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147270/expected-supremum-of-average)

(I'm not aware that this result is well known, or of earlier references).

ADDED:

Consider the associated Poisson process $N(t)$ with $N(0)=0$ and interarrival times $X_i$. Then is is easy to see
that for $a>0$
\begin{align*}
\sup_{t\geq 0}( N(t)-at) \leq 0 \;\; \Longleftrightarrow \;\;\inf_{n\geq 1}\frac{S_n}{n}\geq \frac{1}{a}\end{align*}

It was shown here https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-01/S0002-9947-1957-0084900-X/S0002-9947-1957-0084900-X.pdf and here  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2237099 that
\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{t\geq 0} (N(t)-at)\leq 0)=\Big\{\begin{array}{cc} 1-\frac{1}{a} \mbox {  if  } a\geq 1\\
                                                                       0 \mbox{ else }\end{array}\end{align*}

Thus in this formulation the result is indeed classical.

Comment: Can you provide details of your proof? I don't see how it follows from that answer.

Comment: I confirm that your expression for $\mathbb{P}(R_n>a)$ agrees with what I get from $$\int_{m=a}^\infty\left( g(n,m) + \int_{r=m}^\infty f(n,m,r)dr\right) dm$$

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I've added more details, please let me know if anything's still unclear.

Comment: @Matt F. : thanks for the indepndent confirmation.

Comment: @esg : Thank you for your response.