# An identity for the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Expressing the integral in  [An integral identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377011/an-integral-identity) in terms of residues, we come to the following supposed identity:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1 + W_k(x)}=\frac12$$
for all $x\in(-1/e,0)$, where $W_k$ is the $k$th branch of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

How can this be proved?

Answer (score 2):

This identity is now established, since
[An integral identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377011/an-integral-identity) cited in the above post is now proved.