# Probability that a 1-D zero mean random walk remains at each step inside a square root boundary

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Let $W_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i$ be a random walk on $\mathbb{R}$, where the increments $X_i$ are i.i.d., symmetric around the origin ($X\sim -X$), such that $-1\leq |X(\omega)| \leq 1$ $\forall\omega\in\Omega$, $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $Var(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$. I would like to bound from above the following probability as a function of $k$:
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{|W_n| \leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr)\leq h(k) \mbox{ ?}
$$
where $\lim_{k\to\infty} h(k) =0$, because I manage to prove it using zero-one Kolmogorov's law and the fact that $\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable.

I know that it may be a really simple question, although I just can not find the right bound.. I have tried lots of different techniques but none of them seem to work properly. I think that a useful fact is the simmetry ( since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},W_n\sim-W_n$ ) and the fact that $W_n$ has zero mean and (in general) bounded moments.

**PS**: maybe a more simple question could be to bound from above
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{W_n \leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr)\leq g(k) \mbox{ ?}
$$
using a decreasing function $g(k)$ with the same properties of $h(k)$. Also note that in general:
$$
P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{|W_n| \leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr) \leq P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{W_n\leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr),
$$
so $g(k)$ also bounds $P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{|W_n |\leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr)$.

**Note**

The existence of such $h(k)$ has already been proven by the fact that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{|W_n| \leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr) = 0
$$
although I would like an "analytic" expression for it.

**References**

Maybe the paper "Darling-Erdős theorems for normalized sums of i.i.d. variables close to a stable law"

> https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-26/issue-2/Darling-Erd%C5%91s-theorems-for-normalized-sums-of-iid-variables-close/10.1214/aop/1022855652.full

may help along with the question

> [Concentration inequalities for the maximum of the rescaled/normalized sum of iid random variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146397/concentration-inequalities-for-the-maximum-of-the-rescaled-normalized-sum-of-iid)

In fact

$$
P\Bigl(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{k}\Bigl\{W_n\leq\sqrt{n}\Bigr\}\Bigr)\leq P\Bigl(\max_{1\leq n\leq k}\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 1\Bigl)
$$
which could possibly be bounded from above with some decreasing function $m(k)$ using some of those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m:=\lfloor\log_2 k\rfloor$, so that $2^m\le k<2^{m+1}$. Then the probability in question is
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_k&:=P(|W_n|\le\sqrt n\ \forall n\le k) \\ 
&\le P(|W_{2^j}|\le2^{j/2}\ \forall j\in\{0,\dots,m\}) \\ 
&\le P(|W_{2^j}-W_{2^{j-1}}|\le2^{j/2}+2^{(j-1)/2}\ \forall j\in\{1,\dots,m\}) \\ 
&=\prod_{j=1}^m p_j, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$p_j:=P(|W_{2^j}-W_{2^{j-1}}|\le2^{(j-1)/2}(1+\sqrt2)).$$
Noting that here $E|X_1|^3\le EX_1^2=1/2$ and using the [Berry–Esseen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem#Identically_distributed_summands) with Shevtsova's constant $0.4748<1/2$, we get
$$p_j\le q_j:=\min(1,q+2^{1-j/2}),$$
where
$$q:=P(|B_{2^{j-1}}|/\sqrt2\le2^{(j-1)/2}(1+\sqrt2))
=P(|B_1|\le\sqrt2+2)=0.999360\dots$$
and $B_\cdot$ is a standard Brownian motion.
Since $q_j=1$ iff $j\le23$, we conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_k&\le Cq^{m-23}\le\frac C{q^{24}}\,q^{\log_2k}=\frac C{q^{24}}\,k^{-t},
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$C:=\prod_{j=24}^\infty\Big(1+\frac1q\,2^{1-j/2}\Big)=1.0016\dots$$
(so that $\frac C{q^{24}}=1.017\dots$) and
$$t:=-\frac{\ln q}{\ln2}=0.00092313\dots.$$

---

We see that the exponent $t$ is very small. It can be improved with a bit of extra effort, in particular by using $c^j$ instead of $2^j$ with $c>1$ close to $1$.
However, the improved exponent will still be small. The reason for that can be seen in the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm), which in this case will state that
$$\limsup_n\frac{|W_n|}{\sqrt{n\ln\ln n}}=1,$$
and the fact that $\ln\ln n$ grows very slowly, so that $\sqrt{n\ln\ln n}$ will not differ too much from $\sqrt n$; e.g., $\ln\ln(10^{10})=3.13\dots$. So, the bounds $\sqrt n$ on $|W_n|$ are not too confining to cause $P_k$ go to $0$ perceptibly fast.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, I understand all of your proof.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a similar question for Brownian motion:
$$F(T)=\mathbb{P}(|B_t|\leq \sqrt{t}\quad \forall 1\leq t\leq T).$$
Then, we have $$F(2^N)\leq \mathbb{P}(|B_{t}-B_{2^n}|\leq 2\sqrt{2^{n+1}} \quad \forall n=0,\dots,N-1,\, t\in [2^{n},2^{n+1}]),$$ because if the inequality is not satisfied, then at least one of $B_t$ and $B_{2^n}$ is outside the interval $(-\sqrt{2^{n+1}},\sqrt{2^{n+1}})$. Now, $\{B_t-B_{2^{0}}\}_{t\in[2^0,2^1)},\{B_t-B_{2^{1}}\}_{t\in[2^1,2^2)},\dots$ are independent, and by Brownain scaling, for all $n$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(\max_{t\in[2^n,2^{n+1})}|B_t-B_2^{n}|\leq2\sqrt{2^{n+1}})=\mathbb{P}(\max_{t\in[1,2)}|B_t-B_1|\leq 2\sqrt{2})=:q.
$$
Therefore, $F(2^N)\leq q^N$, that is, $F(T)\leq q^{-1}T^\sigma$, where $\sigma=\frac{\log q}{\log 2}.$

For the random walk, the result will be the same, e.g., by KMT or Skorokhod coupling with the Brownian motion, see e.g. Section 5 of Mörters and Peres book.

Comment: Thank you for all the details you provided! So basically we can interchange $B_t$ with my random walk $W_t$ without any problems?

Comment: For example you have defined $q$ as $q = P(\max_{t\in [1,2)} |B_t-B_1| > 2\sqrt{2})$.. but $t$ belongs to a continous space, while $W_t$ is a discrete time process. How does $q$ change if I substitute $B_t$ with $W_n$? Where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Can you point me where to look for these informations? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @LucaOnnis, if you look at $P(\max_{2^k\leq n\leq 2^{k+1}}|W_n-W_{2^k}|\leq2\sqrt{2^{k+1}}),$ then it will also converge to $q$, by Donsker invariance principle. Coupling arguments also give you the rate of convergence.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understood.

Comment: @Kostya_I : I do not understand why "For the random walk, the result will be the same, e.g., by KMT or Skorokhod coupling with the Brownian motion". There is a discrepancy between the random walk and the Brownian motion. Also, I think a good bound should depend on the variance of $X$. If that variance is small, the bound should be small; also, then the normal approximation will be bad.

Comment: @Kostya_I : I did not read the question carefully enough. Now I see that, instead of "the bound should be small", I should have said "the bound **must** be close to $1$". The rest of the previous comment remains valid, and even acquires a much stronger sense.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thank you for your reply! So.. I agree that the bound has to depend on the variance of the increment $X$ (which is in my case $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$). Have you got an idea for bounding from above that probability using another argument? Maybe using an elementary argument it's possible to find an upper bound, maybe not the best but I think for my purposes should work as well.

Comment: @LucaOnnis : If your $\sigma^2$ is $1/2$, this should be specified in your post. As I wrote, if $\sigma^2$ is very small, the bound must be very different: it must be close to $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Edited. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are several papers discussing the crossing of square root boundary by a random walk, which seem to be relevant.

1. Breiman (1967). First exit times from a square root boundary.  https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Fifth-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/chapter/First-exit-times-from-a-square-root-boundary/bsmsp/1200513456
2. Greenwood and Perkins (1983). A conditioned limit theorem for a random walks and Brownian local time. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-11/issue-2/A-Conditioned-Limit-Theorem-for-Random-Walk-and-Brownian-Local/10.1214/aop/1176993594.full
3. [Edit] Uchiyama (1980). Brownian first exit from and sojourn over one sided moving boundary and application. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00535355

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out these references!

Comment: Breiman's paper is very interesting.. in my case the variance of each increment is $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and I would like to bound the probability that $T_1 = \inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\frac{W_n}{\sqrt{n}} > 1\}$ is bigger than a certain $k$. By rescaling (in order to have unit variance) , the question is equivalent to bound from above the probability $$ P(T_\sqrt{2} > k) = P(\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N} : \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{2}\} > k) \leq h(k) \mbox{ ?}$$ where $S_n = \sqrt{2}W_n$ is a unit variance increment random walk.

Comment: Another intersting question could be to understand whether $\mathbb{E}(T_{\sqrt{2}})$ is finite or not.. and if finite, try to bound it. Do you think it's possible to prove or disprove that its first moment it's finite using the papers you cited?

Comment: Theorem 2 in Breiman says that $P(T_{\sqrt 2}>n)\sim an^{-\beta(c)}$ for some $\beta(\sqrt 2)$. According to https://doi.org/10.1137/1116049 this $\beta(\sqrt{2})$ using the roots of parabolic cylinder function. After quick trial and error it looks as if $\beta(\sqrt{2})\approx 0.115$.