A maximal inequality
Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d. symmetric random variables, with $-1\leq X_i\leq 1$, $\mathbb{E}(X_i) =0$, $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = 1$. We have that:
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{|\sum_{i = 1}^{k}X_i|}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 1\right) = P\left(\max_{k = 1,\dots,n}\frac{|\sum_{i = 1}^{k}X_i|}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 1\right) \geq g(n)\to 0 \mbox{ as $n\to\infty$}
$$
I would like to find a function $n\mapsto g(n)$ such that $g(n) > 0$ which satisfy the condition above $\forall n\geq n_0$, with $n_0$ sufficiently large. Is there a "known" inequality that could help to solve this question?
Update
Using the notations given in the first answer to this post, is it possible to bound $p_{1,2^{r+1}}$ in terms of $p_{1,2^r}$? For example something like:
$$
p_{1,2^{r+1}} \geq p_{1,2^r}h(r)
$$
where $h(r)$ is non trivial (non identically zero, at most it can approaches $0$ as $r\to\infty$, although it would be better if $h(r) \geq c>0$). Note that in general $p_{1,2^{r+1}} \leq p_{1,2^{r}}$, so I'm asking for a function $h$ that "flips" the inequality.
An example for $h(r)$ is the following:
$$
h(r) = \min_{x\in[-\sqrt{2^{r}},\sqrt{2^r}]}P\left(|S_k -S_{2^r}+ x| \leq\sqrt{2^r} ,\forall m\in\{2^{r}+1,\dots,2^{r+1}\}\right)
$$
Can we do better? Because in general this function goes to $0$ really quickly.
Important
Probably I solved it, I'll post an answer soon.

There's also an issue for $k=1$. What if $X_1$ is $\pm \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\epsilon\right)$ with probability $1-\delta$ (each sign with probability $\frac{1-\delta}{2}$) and $0$ with probability $\delta$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is small and $\delta > 0$ is chosen so that $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] = \frac{1}{2}$. As $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, also $\delta \downarrow 0$, so there's no universal $g(1)$ that works.

Okay maybe I could request that the inequality definitely works for all $n\geq n_0$ , with $n_0$ sufficiently large. Thank you for pointing this out!

In any event, the events are positively correlated (right now, I don't have a proof, but it should certainly be true!), and for large $n$, each has a constant $>0$ chance of being true (certainly at least $10^{-10}$). So you can take $g(n) = 10^{-10n}$.

(By the way, your fix doesn't work, since $\epsilon,\delta$ in my above comment could depend on $n_0$. The correct fix would be to take the maximum from $k=n_0$ to $n$ rather than from $k=1$ to $n$).

The $X_i$s are bounded and hence subgaussian; the expected maximum behaves as $\sqrt{\log n}$ and it's tightly concentrated about the mean. You can find all of this in the Boucheron,  Lugosi,  Massart book Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence. Let me know if you manage to extract an answer from this. If not, I could make it into one in a day or so.

What about https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146397/concentration-inequalities-for-the-maximum-of-the-rescaled-normalized-sum-of-iid?noredirect=1&lq=1 @mathworker21? Could help?

Because of the $k$ in the denominator, you'll get a tighter bound if you use a maximal inequality for non-homogeneous subgaussians. See Lemma 9 here https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.04054

You can apply Hoeffding's Lemma to each $X_k/k$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma

@AryehKontorovich I see your work and in particular Lemma 9, which gives a very nice tight bound. In my case $Y_k = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{k}X_i}{\sqrt{k/2}}$.. but you bound $P(\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} [Y_k]{+} \geq t)$, how to use this fact to bound $P(\sup{k\in\mathbb{N}}|Y_k| \leq 1)$?

Just add a factor of 2

I just noticed that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\sum_{i = 1}^{k} X_i$ is a 1-sub gaussian, isn't it? Because $X_i \sim subG(1)$ since it's bounded between $-1$ and $1$. Furthermore the $X_i$ are indipendent and so $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} X_i \sim subG(k)$, and finally by scaling by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ we obtain this result.

@MathRevenge use our Lemma 9 to bound the expectation and then use a deviation bound (such as McDiarmid's inequality)?

actually, this Exercise 6.5 from Boucheron et al. will probably give better concentration than McDiarmid
https://ibb.co/tmrbrmd
please let me know if you get stuck and I'll work it out in an answer

@AryehKontorovich https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00354762 could be helpful?

@MathRevenge I believe so, yes. Especially if you don't care about bounds for finite $n$ but only about the asymptotics -- that seems to be fully resolved there. Can you try to work it out?

Well, I would prefer a bound which holds for finite $n$, since I already know that the probability in question approaches $0$ as $n$ increases. For example by simulating on R I understand that it goes to $0$ really slowly, slower than $\frac{1}{n}$.. so an example for $g(n)$ would be exactly $\frac{1}{n}$, but how to prove it?

$\newcommand\ol\overline$In accordance with the comment by the OP, consider
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}:=P\Big(\max_{k\in\ol{N,n}}\frac{|S_k|}{\sqrt{k/2}}\le1\Big),
\end{equation*}
where $\ol{A,B}:=\{k\in\Bbb Z\colon A\le k\le B\}$ and $S_k:=\sum_1^k X_i$.
Let us show that for all large enough $N$ and all $n\ge N$
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}=n^{-c}; \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
here and in what follows $c$ denotes various expressions that are $\asymp1$.
Indeed, without loss of generality $N=2^{r_0}$ for some natural $r_0\ge2$ and $n=2^r$ for some natural $r>r_0$. Then
\begin{align*}
p_{N,n}&= P(|S_k|\le\sqrt{k/2}\ \ \forall j\in\ol{r_0+1,r}\ \forall k\in\ol{2^{j-1},2^j}) \\ 
&\ge P(|S_{2^{j-1}}|\le b_{j-1}, |S_k|\le b_j\ \ 
\forall j\in\ol{r_0+1,r}\ \forall k\in\ol{2^{j-1}+1,2^j}),      
\end{align*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    b_j:=\sqrt{2^{j-2}+1/2}. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}\ge\prod_{j=r_0+1}^r q_j,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
    q_j&:=\min_{x\in[-b_{j-1},b_{j-1}]}P(|S_k-S_{2^{j-1}}+x|\le b_j\ \ \forall k\in\ol{2^{j-1}+1,2^j}) \\  
    &:=\min_{x\in[-b_{j-1},b_{j-1}]}P(|S_m+x|\le b_j\ \ \forall m\in\ol{1,2^{j-1}}) \\  
    &\to\min_{u\in[-1/2,1/2]}P(|W_t+u|\le1/\sqrt2\ \ \forall t\in[0,1])=:q>0  
\end{align*}
as $j\to\infty$ by the invariance principle.
So, for all large enough $N$ and all $n\ge N$
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}\ge c_1(q/2)^{r-r_0}= c_1n^{-c}, \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
where $c_1:=P(|S_{2^{r_0}}|\le b_{r_0})(q/2)^{-r_0}>0$ (by the central limit theorem) if $N=2^{r_0}$ is large enough.
On the other hand, again for $N=2^{r_0}$ and $n=2^r$ with $r>r_0$,
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}\le\prod_{j=r_0+1}^r Q_j,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
    Q_j&:=P(|S_{2^j}-S_{2^{j-1}}|\le\sqrt{2^{j-1}/2}+\sqrt{2^j}/2)\to Q\in(0,1)
\end{align*}
as $j\to\infty$ by the central limit theorem.
So, for $Q_1:=(1+Q)/2\in(0,1)$ and all large enough $N$ and all $n\ge N$
\begin{equation*}
    p_{N,n}\le Q_1^{r-r_0}=n^{-c}. \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
Now \eqref{10} follows from \eqref{20} and \eqref{30}. $\quad\Box$.

Thank you very much for pointing out this idea! But..there is no way to adjust this argument in order to fix $N = 1$? So that we can consider the maximum of the first $n$ instead of the maximum between the $N$-th and $n$-th observation. Please let me know and thank you again.

@MathRevenge : I followed your linked comment, made in response to the earlier comment by mathworker21.

I meant that the inequality works for all sufficiently large $n$, but I would like $N = 1$ (using your notations).. although mathworker21 said that there are no such $g(n)$.. but I don't understand why it is not the case. By simulating it seems that $1/n$ works (for example). But we have to prove it, or at least find such a function $g$, eventually different but such that it satisfy the property.

@MathRevenge : Note that $p_{1,n}\le p_{1,1}$ and, as noted in the mentioned comment by mathworker21, $p_{1,1}$ can be however small. So, $p_{1,n}$ can be however small.

In my case $p_{1,1} \approx 0.5$.. I'm searching for a bound similar to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146397/concentration-inequalities-for-the-maximum-of-the-rescaled-normalized-sum-of-iid?noredirect=1&lq=1 (look at the first answer). By the way, we can use the bound in this question by moving on to complementaries, but it gaves a "trivial" bound which is not useful at all. I need something like $p_{1,n} \geq g(n)$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

@MathRevenge : What do you mean by "my case"?

I'm trying to understand a more general case.. where we only have these hypothesis. Although this problem was born when I was considering $X_i = \cos{\theta_i}$ with $\theta_i$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. For example, in this case, is there such a function $g$? And if the answer is positive, based on the nature of the $X_i$ could we find a general $g$ (which depends on $X$) which atisfy the inequality above?

@MathRevenge : The bound in that answer is an upper bound on a large deviation probability, whereas your question is about a lower bound on a small deviation probability. The two questions have nothing to do with each other.

@MathRevenge : Your post does not have any specifics as $X_i=\cos\theta_i$. Let's just stick to what your post says.

Well, $P(\max_{k=1,\dots,n}\frac{S_k}{c_k} \leq 1) = 1 - P(\max_{k=1,\dots,n}\frac{S_k}{c_k} \geq 1) \geq 1 - h(n) = g(n)$ where $h(n)$ is given by that answer. But as I said, it gaves a "trivial" bound since $g(n)$ becames eventually a negative number.

@MathRevenge : This approach will not work, because what you denoted by $g(n)$ in your latter comment will likely be greater than $1$. It is highly unlikely that it will be like $1-n^{-c}$, as it would have to be according to my answer.

Of course, in this case it doesn't work as I said.. but maybe there exist other bounds I don't know which we can use to solve this! My question is all about the existence of such a function $g$ given the nature of the $X_i$ which satisfy the bound above. Anyway your answer teaches me a good technique. So thank you! Upvoted.

@MathRevenge : Well, again: it follows from the comment by mathworker21 that $p_{1,1}$ can be however small and hence $p_{1,n}$ can be however small. So, no nonzero lower bound on $p_{1,n}$ exists in general, and the distribution of the $X_i$'s is not specified in your post.

I understand now! Ok.. thank you for your time and for your precious help.

Hi @Iosif Pinelis, is there a "straight forward" way to approximate the limit $q = \lim_{j\to\infty}q_j$?

I'm having trouble in understanding this step: $\min_{x\in[-b_{j-1},b_{j-1}]}P(|S_m+x|\le b_j\  \forall m\in{1,\dots,2^{j-1})\to\min_{u\in[-1/2,1/2]}P(|W_t+u|\le1/\sqrt2\ \forall t\in[0,1])$ . I guess you are dividing by $\sqrt{2^{j-1}+1}$ each term.. but then the variable $u\in[-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}]$, not $u\in[-1/2,1/2]$.. Probably I'm making some obvious mistakes, but I would like if you could help me and explain this step. Thank you in advance!

@MathRevenge : Concerning your penultimate comment, there are somewhat explicit bounds on the rate of convergence in the invariance principle. See e.g. papers by Borovkov. But, no, there is no easy way to derive such bounds.

@MathRevenge : Concerning your latter comment, we divide $b_{j-1}\sim2^{(j-3)/2}$ by $\sim2^{(j-1)/2}$ and get $\sim1/2$.

Thank you @Iosif Pinelis for your patience. Regarding the approximation of the limit $q$ I think that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356903/running-maximum-absolute-value-of-wiener-process and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126681/distribution-of-max-t-in-0-1-w-t-for-brownian-motion/3126708#3126708 may help! Indeed, in this case the minimum is reached at $u = \frac{1}{2}$ and that probability is approximately $q \approx 0.0479435$

@MathRevenge : I guess I misunderstood you "approximate the limit". I thought you were concerned with the rate of convergence of $q_j$ to $q$. Of course, there is no problem finding $q$ with any degree of accuracy.
